# Simple HTML and PHP test

Tags: php, html

I'm using wamp server for testing my php scripts. I just got an error on one of my recent projects so I created a basic example and found out that it isn't working. So, in my www folder, I have 2 files:
MyApp.html
MyApp.php

MyApp.html body:

```
<div id="tab">
        <form action="MyApp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit1">
            <br>
        </form>
</div>
```

MyApp.php:

```
if ($_POST['submit1']) {
$test = 'ThisIsMyApp';
print($test);}
```

So what I want to do here is to press submit button, and it should print "ThisIsMyApp" from php file. I open .html file on my localhost, and after I click submit button, I get this error:

Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

How do I fix that?

Comment: unless you have mod_rewrite doing something fancy, there is more to this than youare showing.

Comment: Did you try to create a index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

1st of all make sure both of them are in the same directory.
and do your MyApp.php has the php tags?

```
<?php ---your code--- ?>
```